# Button and EditText check

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, textview

I have one EditText, TextView and one button. When i`m pressing it, textview updates by append(). But when i'm pressing this button in the next time, text adds again, updating my textview. How i can handle this? 
Without something like:

```
btn.setClickable(false);
```

or

```
btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

because if the text in the EditText field updates, button must work.

Comment: btn.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to do two things:

- disable the button as soon as it is pressed, to prevent updating the TextView twice with the same text by calling `btn.setEnabled(false);`
- reenable the button as soon as the EditText content changes. That can be done with a TextWatcher.

An example for the TextWatcher implementation looks like this:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
       btn.setEnabled(true);
    }

 });
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Disable button when you press it and enable it when the text in the EditText is changed, as such:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        appendToEditText();
        btn.setClickable(false);
    }
});

EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // Not Used

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // Not Used

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        btn.setClickable(true);
    } 
});
```